How to Find Out Which Columns in a Table are Queried by SELECT and UPDATE Statements
We have a table that has 54 columns, it is used by many applications, reports and users.
The table is from legacy system, some columns may be obsolete.
We would like to find out which exactly columns are actually used - by SELECT and UPDATE queries. How can this be found out?
If this is possible, we would like to get it in below format:
Column1 - SELECT - 1,890,123 times 
Column1 - UPDATE - 2,394 times 
Column2 - SELECT - 5,222,456 times 
Column2 - UPDATE - 567 times 
Column3...

One idea was to scan all GIT repositories (source code of apps) for those columns, but some apps might not be in GIT actually. And reports are not in GIT.
Above research is for:

To find out columns that are not queried at all, and possibly get rid of them.
To find out columns that are queried a lot, and not updated, review possibility of create nonclustered columnstore index.


You can enable Query Store on each database that might contain queries referencing this table. For example, the table Post is queried in the StackOverflow database but can also be queried in other databases.
Once enabled, use Query Store views to count executions by query type (e.g., SELECT and UPDATE) for each column.
I use the sp_MSforeachdb to query the Query Store views in each database.
The code example is for the Posts table of the StackOverflow. You can modify it to fit your case.
/** SET UP THE TABLE #ColumnsToSearch**/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ColumnsToSearch
CREATE TABLE #ColumnsToSearch
(
    column_ varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #ColumnsToSearch
VALUES
('Id'),
('AcceptedAnswerId'),
('AnswerCount'),
('Body'),
('ClosedDate'),
('CommentCount'),
('CommunityOwnedDate'),
('CreationDate'),
('FavoriteCount'),
('LastActivityDate'),
('LastEditDate'),
('OnwerUserId'),
('ParentId'),
('PostTypeId'),
('Score'),
('Tags'),
('Title')

/** SET UP THE TABLE #ResultsByDatabase**/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ResultsByDatabase
CREATE TABLE #ResultsByDatabase
(
    db VARCHAR(50),
    column_ varchar(50),
    QueryType VARCHAR(10),
    count_executions bigint
);

/**COLLECT BY DATABASE**/
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql
= '
USE [?];
INSERT INTO #ResultsByDatabase
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(),
    column_,
    QueryType,
    sum(count_executions) AS count_executions
FROM 
(
    SELECT c.column_,
        CASE WHEN query_sql_text LIKE ''%SELECT%'' THEN ''SELECT'' ELSE ''UPDATE'' END AS QueryType,
        qsrs.count_executions 
    FROM sys.query_store_query_text qsqt
    INNER JOIN sys.query_store_query qsq
        ON qsqt.query_text_id = qsq.query_text_id
    INNER JOIN sys.query_store_plan qsp
        ON qsq.query_id = qsp.query_id
    INNER JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsrs
        ON qsp.plan_id = qsrs.plan_id
    INNER JOIN #ColumnsToSearch c
        ON query_sql_text LIKE ''%''+c.column_ +''%'' -- filter queries contain the columns of the tables
    WHERE 
        query_sql_text LIKE ''%Posts%'' -- filter queries contain the table name
        AND (query_sql_text LIKE ''%SELECT%'' OR query_sql_text LIKE ''%UPDATE%'') -- filter queries contain the SELECT or UPDATE keywords
) x
GROUP BY column_,
    QueryType'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @sql

/**FINAL RESULT**/
SELECT 
    column_,
    QueryType,
    SUM(count_executions) count_executions
FROM #ResultsByDatabase
GROUP BY column_,
    QueryType


The returned result will look like this:

You can configure Query Store - to retain your data longer, to cover rare executions, before collecting the execution counts. For example, collect and retain one year data before querying the Query Store views and making any decision on the table.


Query store seems a reasonable way of getting the adhoc SQL and execution counts, probably will be more reliable to take that and chuck it into a helper proc and then can call sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.HelperProc', 'OBJECT') to get the info on column references and how they are used –
or extract it from the plan XML which would be considerably more work but may be the only option (other than using a SQL parser) if the statement references #temp tables or table variables created in an earlier statement

Uhm yes you can do WHEN "UPDATE" THEN "UPDATE" too. But since the WHERE clause already filters (query_sql_text LIKE ''%SELECT%'' OR query_sql_text LIKE ''%UPDATE%'') , so I can just use the ELSE

Not a super perfect solution, since it would capture queries like "UPDATE #Posts SET Column1 =..." where temp table name contains table name in question, and some column names are the same.
Or "INSERT Posts SELECT column1... from #temp" where column names in #temp  are same as in Posts, for example.  In my system table names are different, of course, just using Posts name here so its more clear what I mean.

So you can imagine there are a lot of exceptions and you have to handle them in the WHERE condition properly, to make it work. But, this is the right direction and a good answer, so accepting it.
